# Why is my Tensorflow training hanging indefinitely with no errors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

After setting up tensorflow, verifying gpu acceleration is working, set up configs, everything in this tutorial https://github.com/nicknochnack/TFODCourse.

I run:

```
py Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=100
```

And get these output logs, wait over an hour, Python continuously uses 25-26% of my CPU, but no progress logs are ever printed, even when I lower the steps to 100, I get nothing:

There are a bunch of warnings, but maybe that's normal? I've googled some of the INFO logs and found they're harmless. What does it seem I've missed or done wrong from these logs? Here are the abridged logs with future deprecation warnings removed:

```
2021-07-11 02:25:42.869766: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
    py Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=100
    2021-07-11 02:25:44.989884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.588384: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.605286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
    pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
    coreClock: 1.845GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 462.00GiB/s
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.605366: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.610303: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.610390: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.613585: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.614873: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.621607: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.623967: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.624496: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.626311: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.626728: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
    To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.627707: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
    pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
    coreClock: 1.845GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 462.00GiB/s
    2021-07-11 02:25:47.627810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2021-07-11 02:25:48.067610: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2021-07-11 02:25:48.067778: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
    2021-07-11 02:25:48.068662: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
    2021-07-11 02:25:48.069323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5957 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
    WARNING:tensorflow:Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
    W0711 02:25:48.071784 10384 mirrored_strategy.py:379] Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
    INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
    I0711 02:25:48.225363 10384 mirrored_strategy.py:369] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
    INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: 100
    I0711 02:25:48.229352 10384 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: 100
    INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
    I0711 02:25:48.230349 10384 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
    INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
    I0711 02:25:48.308165 10384 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted datasets: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
    INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
    I0711 02:25:48.309138 10384 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record datasets for input file: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
    INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
    I0711 02:25:48.311132 10384 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 1
    WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
    W0711 02:25:48.311132 10384 dataset_builder.py:87] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
 tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

The full logs including the future deprecation warnings are [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jt0dd/d17936cca18affe08b5af157f363186b), but again, the only difference if future deprecation warnings, nothing that should be broken.

I'm just not sure how to debug this. It looks like it's working, then just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a GitHub issue where others had the same problem.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9581

The issue is my TFRecord generation script couldn't find any images and created empty record files. Both the generation script and Tensorflow unfortunately both silently fail in this case.